# How to wrap a third party API endpoint call, to download a file, into my new API and expose an endpoint to allow to do the same?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am creating a new wrapper spring boot API which is a single interface to many third parties APIs. How should I wrap the third-party endpoint which allows us to download a file?

Comment: Your question has several questions. This against SO rules, if you want to ask more than 1 question - ask it in a new question or remove the second question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just return a byte array in your controller method;

```
@GetMapping()
public @ResponseBody byte[] getImageWithMediaType() throws IOException {
    InputStream in = ...

    return IOUtils.toByteArray(in);
}
```

Comment: My issue is not with the POJO but while downloading a file.

Comment: Sorry, I had misunderstood the question. I have already corrected the answer.

Comment: Thanks @juanmorschrott, unfortunately not able to vote because of my lower reputation.